# Virtual Special Issues in Elsevier good or not?

Tags: research-process, peer-review, elsevier, special-issue

From the information available online, I understand that Virtual Special Issues (VSIs) can be either curated (comprising previously published articles) or dedicated to new work.

As a PhD student, I need to publish an article in a journal with an impact factor for my PhD defense.
Is the credibility of a virtual special issue similar to a regular issue?
How long does the review process for a virtual special issue take?
Considering my time constraints, would the special issue be a viable option for submission?

Comment: Is your main concern about it being virtual/digital only? I think being digital-only or not doesn't say anything about the credibility of the journal, nowadays you have several good journals that don't print out physical magazines.

Comment: Given the second paragraph, the only people who can answer are your local professors or administrators. Our opinion does not matter.

Comment: By the way, you have several questions in your text, you should focus on only one at time.